# Why is my character going through walls in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made simple character with first person movement. I'm not using `CharacterController` since I won't have more control over its physics. Characters' `Rigidbody` isn't kinematic and all the collision matrixes are correct in project editor, but player still goes through the walls. This is how I'm moving the character:

```
playerRb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime) + (transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
```

And this is my characters' `Rigidbody` component: [Rigidbody component screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv0Mh.jpg)

Comment: Are there any specific reason why you are not setting your character as kinematic?

Comment: When `isKinematic` is checked, `Rigidbody` ignores any collision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigidbody.MovePosition is only for kinematic rigidbodies and ignores physics.
Docs say:

> Moves the kinematic Rigidbody towards position.

[documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

And older docs even said:

> If the rigidbody has isKinematic set to false, it works like
> transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object to the new
> position (rather than performing a smooth transition).

(according to this [forum entry](https://forum.unity.com/threads/moveposition-with-interpolation-without-the-rigidbody-being-kinematic.835264/))

So I would suggest that you simply set a velocity in the desired direction. If you need help with that, comment where you have difficulties and I will help you.